# Get the original layout names in Google Slides templates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

We have a template in google slides that was created for us by someone else. The current layout names are different to the original layout names.

[image: Layouts in google slides]

We are using Google App Script to insert images into a template. However, the predefined layouts don't have the custom layouts we are looking for.

Here's some of the code. The code works, but it does not display the layout we want to use.

```
var NAME = ("Price Changes, Earnings Revisions and F-GPE");
var deck = SlidesApp.openById("1bmDMb9OtmLzFT_ow-1j62tfsfDgEwsfY_-APz3fhLfs");

/**
  * Creates a single slide using the image from the given link;
  * used directly by foreach(), hence the parameters are fixed.
  *
  * @param {Date} link A String object representing an image URL
  * @param {Date} index The index into the array; unused (req'd by forEach)
  */
function addImageSlide(imageUrl, index) {
    var slide = deck.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.TITLE);
    var image = slide.insertImage(imageUrl);
    var imgWidth   = image.getWidth();
    var imgHeight  = image.getHeight();
    var pageWidth  = deck.getPageWidth();
    var pageHeight = deck.getPageHeight();
    var newX = pageWidth/2.  - imgWidth/2.;
    var newY = pageHeight/2. - imgHeight/2.;
    image.setLeft(newX).setTop(newY);
}

/**
 * The driver application features an array of image URLs, setting of the
 * main title & subtitle, and creation of individual slides for each image.
 */
function main() {
    var images = [
        "https://product.datastream.com/dscharting/gateway.aspx?guid=be998f9e-9a14-466c-b76b-fd7f551cccf1&action=REFRESH",
        "https://product.datastream.com/dscharting/gateway.aspx?guid=64a0d7bd-599a-4c06-85fc-cfba7c09e26e&action=REFRESH",
        "https://product.datastream.com/dscharting/gateway.aspx?guid=183c43b8-c149-49bb-a14e-50a92100b1b3&action=REFRESH",               
    ];
    var [title, subtitle] = deck.getSlides()[0].getPageElements();
    title.asShape().getText().setText(NAME);
    subtitle.asShape().getText().setText("GLOBAL SHARES WATCHLIST");
    images.forEach(addImageSlide);
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Are you trying to override the layouts shown when one clicks "Layouts"?

Comment: My question is how to add custom layouts to the predefined layouts.

Comment: the predefined layouts list includes: BLANK
                                                         TITLE
                                                         TITLE_ONLY
                                                          -
                                                          -
I want my own layouts to display

Comment: Please take note that "**These are commonly found layouts in presentations. However, there is no guarantee that these layouts are present in the current master as they could have been deleted or not part of the used theme. Additionally, the placeholders on each layout may have been changed.**" as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#PredefinedLayout). Maybe this is the reason why your layout doesn't display.